# Wamp ProjectPier Installation Error

Tags: php, ldap, wampserver, projectpier

I am new to ProjectPier and Wamp. Through Wamp, I have been attempting to install the latest version of ProjectPier and am seeing the following message on one of the install screens: "Warning: 'ldap' extension is not available (check documentation)" I have enabled the php_ldap extension on Wamp.

Any advice?

Comment: You need a older version of Wamp. New one does it. I cannot remember which one you should use but if I could remember I'll tell you. I had exactly the same issue and solved by downgrading.

Comment: I think it was wamp 1.9 working for me. Try and see how it goes. For ldap connection, you just had to enable extebsion. That's the way it worked for me. No extra configs.

Comment: I ended up installing version 2.4 and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on wamp and navigate to php extensions.

Find ldap and toggle it.

Restart wamp if needed.

Comment: Try opening the httpd.conf file and finding ldap and ensuring it isn't commented out. If that fails, check your wamp version and if ldap is bundled within the php installer it contains. Try a different wamp version which bundles php ldap.